# Elements visible only from Inspector, SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I've tried to create more circles with button, but it doesnt work. Theyre shown in the Mozilla Inspector after click:

[inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFSGc.png)
but theyre not visible for me. I've seen similiar problems here, but there wasn't single one that works. Can you help me please? Atm I have no idea what to do.

circle.js

```
class Circle {
constructor(id, posx, posy, r, fill) {
    this.id = id;
    this.posx = posx;
    this.posy = posy;
    this.r = r;
    this.fill = fill;
}}
```

creator.js

```
function createCircle() {

let color = ["blue", "black", "red", "green", "purple", "orange", "yellow"]
const circle = new Circle("node", 100, 100, 50, color[0]);

var node = document.createElement("CIRCLE");
node.setAttribute("id", "node");
node.setAttribute("cx", circle.posx);
node.setAttribute("cy", circle.posy);
node.setAttribute("r", circle.r);
node.setAttribute("fill", circle.fill);
document.getElementById("frame").appendChild(node);

console.log(circle.fill);}
```

body and  from index.html

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
<svg id="sss" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <svg id="frame" width="1020px" height="820px" viewBox="0 0 1020 820">
        <circle id="circle0" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="black" />
    </svg>
</svg>
<button onclick="createCircle()">Create circle</button></body>
```

Comment: And btw, first circle  is visible from the start:
"<circle id="circle0" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="black" />"
Only next ones doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@gdanielyan's answer is a good answer. Here is a demo:

```js
class Circle {
constructor(id, posx, posy, r, fill) {
    this.id = id;
    this.posx = posx;
    this.posy = posy;
    this.r = r;
    this.fill = fill;
}}

function createCircle() {

let color = ["blue", "red", "green", "purple", "orange", "yellow"]
const circle = new Circle("node", 100, 100, 50, color[0]);

var node = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","circle");
node.setAttributeNS(null,"id", "node");
node.setAttributeNS(null,"cx", circle.posx + Math.random()*100);
node.setAttributeNS(null,"cy", circle.posy + Math.random()*100);
node.setAttributeNS(null,"r", circle.r);
  let _color=color[~~(Math.random()*(color.length))];
  //console.log(_color)
node.setAttributeNS(null,"fill", _color);
document.getElementById("frame").appendChild(node);
}
```

```html
<svg id="sss" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <svg id="frame" width="1020px" height="820px" viewBox="0 0 1020 820">
        <circle id="circle0" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="black" />
    </svg>
</svg>
<button onclick="createCircle()">Create circle</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

SVG elements are from a different namespace than typical HTML elements. An HTML document can mix tags from different XML dialects, for example XHTML, which are the standard HTML elements, but also different dialects as well, like the SVG namespace. In order to create the right element from the correct namespace you need to use a different JavaScript method that lets you specify the namespace:

```
document.createElementNS(namespace, element);
```

The first argument is the namespace so you should use: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", and the second is the element, in this case "circle". So try:

```
var node = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
```

If you're more interested, check out MDN docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS

Comment: Yea I did this and nothing changed. Is this maybe problem with my <body> ?

Comment: Glad it works. Your index.html should have <head> and <html> tags as well. Also, you have an inline function call to myFunction() in the body tag, not sure if you're actually defining that somewhere else.